# PHP ORM DOCTRINE

Tags: php, orm, doctrine

I have problems using the orm doctrine in my code
when I execute the php command bin/console doctrine:database:create

This gives me an error:

Could not create database `my_db_name` for connection named default
An exception occurred in the driver: could not find driver

i'm training to increase my php skills